# how to use the slots in Slider object of ipyvuetify?

Tags: python, vuetify.js, ipywidgets

I'm using the `ipyvuetify` librairy to create a dashboard application. I would like to add an extra `TextField` as a slot to my `Slider` component. I followed the example given in the [vuetify documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/sliders/) and the [slot documentation from ipyvuetify](https://ipyvuetify.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_usage.html#scoped-slots) but I don't manage to make the simple "+" icon to appear.

```py
range = v.RangeSlider(
    v_model = None,
    v_slots = [{
        'name': 'append',
        'children': [v.Icon(children=['mdi-plus'])]
    }]
)
range
```

What did I miss ? Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is not working because the `v_model` of a `RangeSlider` is a list.

```
range_ = v.RangeSlider(
    v_model = [1,2],
    min=1,
    max=10,
    v_slots = [{
        'name': 'append',
        'children': [v.Icon(children=['mdi-plus'])]
    }]
)
range_
```

However, as the documented `v_slot`bug in `ipyvuetify`, the slot will disappear as soon as you interact with the slider.

A workaround could be create a custom range slider with `append_icon` parameter (if you're looking an icon as slot).

```
class RangeSlider(v.RangeSlider):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.append_icon='mdi-plus'
        
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        
        self.on_event('click:append', self.add)
    
    def add(self, *args):
        self.v_model = [self.v_model[0]] + [self.v_model[1]+1]
        
rs=RangeSlider(min=1, max=10, v_model = [1,2])
rs
```

But if you're planning to include a `TextField`, I would create a custom `Flex` element with both widgets linked.

Comment: This is what I've done as a workaround, I obviously want to use a TextField in there. I just wanted to do something more elegant

Answer (score 0):

Slots are tricky and not fully supported as @dguerrero mentioned.  For textfields, would this work using jsdlink instead?

```py
import ipyvuetify as v
import ipywidgets as widgets

rangeSlider = v.RangeSlider(class_='pa-2',
        thumb_label = True, 
        style_="max-width:500px",
        height = 90,
        v_model=[0,10.0],
        min=0,
        max=10.0,
        step=0.01,
        label='min/max:',
        vertical = False,
)

textField = v.TextField(class_='pa-2',
    style_="max-width:100px",
    v_model=rangeSlider.v_model,
    placeholder='',
    label='',
    disabled=False
)

widgets.jsdlink((rangeSlider,'v_model'),(textField,'v_model'))

v.Row(children=[rangeSlider,textField])
```

Comment: I think that is what he suggested and this is what I implemented myself : https://github.com/12rambau/bfast_gpu/blob/master/component/widget/date_range_slider.py